# django how to run a script in the background and notify

Tags: django, django-views

django how to run a script in the background that accepts arguments and notify when the script completes.
Bascically i have a big job that takes time to run .So i want to supply the argument to the python script ,run it in the background and when it completes mail the result link to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/). Last part of the task should be sending the mail.